# Thermal motion at higher pressures at constant temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas

I would like to know if the thermal motion of molecules stays constant if the pressure is increased at constant temperature or not. The viscosity increases with pressure, thus the friction between the molecules also. If the thermal energy is constant, will the motion of the molecules decrease due to higher friction?

Comment: Look at it this way: if you are increasing pressure, you are doing work on the system. where do you think the energy goes !?

Comment: In the ideal gas limit, viscosity becomes independent of pressure..  See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al.

Comment: Thanks for the anwers. I forgot to add that I am speaking of a liquid,.